# How would you represent a 2D matrix as an input state and have it select the index of the row it thinks is the best action for that state?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to build an RL model where the input is a NxM matrix, N being the number of selectable actions and M being features describing the action.

In all the RL problems I've seen so far, the state space is either a vector and passed in to a regular neural network or an image and is passed in through a convolutional neural network.

But say we have an environment where the objective is to learn to select the strongest worker for a fixed task, and a single state representation looked like this:

```
names = ['Bob','Henry','Mike','Phil']
max_squat = [300,400,200,100]
max_bench = [200,100,225,100]
max_deadlift = [600,400,300,225]
strongest_worker_df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':names,'Max_Squat':max_squat,'Max_Bench':max_bench,'Max_Deadlift':max_deadlift})
```

[image]

I want to pass in this 2D matrix (without Name column of course) as an input and have it return a row index, and then pass that row index as an action to the environment and get a reward. Then run a reinforcement learning algorithm on the gradient of the reward with respect to the action selection.

Any suggestions on how to go about this, specifically the state representation?

Answer (score 0):

Well as long as your matrix is of fixed size (N and M don't change), you could just vectorize it (concatenate rows) and the network would work like that.

It is perhaps suboptimal to do this though because given the problem setting it seems preferable to maybe pass each row through the same neural net to get features and then have a top level discriminator that operates on the concatenated features.

An example model that would do this (in TensorFlow code) is:

```
model_input = x = Input(shape=(N, M))
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = Dense(16, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)

# The layers above this line define the feature generator, at this point
# your model has 16 fetaures for every person, i.e. an Nx16 matrix.
# Each person's feature have gone through the same nodes and have received
# the same transformations from them.

x = Flatten()(x)

# The Nx16 matrix is now flattened and below define the discriminator
# which will have a softmax output of size N (the highest output identifies
# the selected index)

x = Dense(16, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = Dense(16, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = Dense(16, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = Dense(N, activation='softmax')(x)


model = Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=x)
```